# How To Upload File To Remote Sitecore Instance Via Web Request

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am attempting to upload a PDF file to Sitecore as a single web request and have it added to the media library. I would like to choose a parent folder and have all requests generate a PDF at that location with the provided file name.

It appears that SPE is capable of such a feat, but the similar questions/blogs that I've found thus far do not quite provide the answers I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

First, ensure you have [Sitecore Remoting enabled](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/remoting).

Next, ensure the restfulv1 service is enabled (NOTE: I just set up the admin user for a quick and dirty example):

```
<powershell>
      <services>
        <restfulv1>
          <patch:attribute name="enabled">true</patch:attribute>
          <authorization>
              <add name="isadmin" Permission="Allow" IdentityType="Role" Identity="sitecore\IsAdministrator" />
              <add name="superuser" Permission="Allow" IdentityType="User" Identity="sitecore\superuser" />
            </authorization>
        </restfulv1>
     <remoting>
      <patch:attribute name="enabled">true</patch:attribute>
      <authorization>
        <add name="isadmin" Permission="Allow" IdentityType="Role" Identity="sitecore\IsAdministrator" />
        <add name="superuser" Permission="Allow" IdentityType="User" Identity="sitecore\superuser" />
      </authorization>
    </remoting>
      </services>
</powershell>
```

The following Powershell script provides the backbone for uploading a PDF via a standard HTTP Request:

```
$parentMediaFolder = "$([Sitecore.Constants]::MediaLibraryPath)/Files/"
$fileName = $scriptArguments["fileName"]
$fileNameNoExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($fileName);$mediaCreatorOptions = New-Object Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions
$mediaCreatorOptions.Database = [Sitecore.Configuration.Factory]::GetDatabase("master")
$mediaCreatorOptions.Versioned = [Sitecore.Configuration.Settings+Media]::UploadAsVersionableByDefault;
$mediaCreatorOptions.Destination =  $parentMediaFolder + $fileNameNoExtension$mediaCreator = New-Object Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator$createdMediaItem = $mediaCreator.AttachStreamToMediaItem($($requestStreams.Values)[0], $parentMediaFolder + $fileNameNoExtension, $fileName, $mediaCreatorOptions)
write-host $createdMediaItem.ID
Add this script to Sitecore.
```

Usage:

Use Postman to construct a request with these settings:

**Verb**: POST

**URL**: https://cminstance.local/sitecore%20modules/PowerShell/Services/RemoteScriptCall.ashx

**Query String parameters**:

- script: the full path to the SPE script
- sc_database: master
- apiVersion: 1 (this is a toggler for a variety of functions available in the RemoteScriptCall service, we need 1 in order to execute a script)
- fileName: A custom parameter. We can add as many as we need. This includes the file extension. This is sent to the SPE script.

**Body**: Choose "form-data", add a "KEY" named "File" and modify the "VALUE" value and choose a PDF to attach to the request.

**Authorization (tab)**: Select "Basic auth"

Enter the username as "sitecore\<username>" and the password

**Response**: The ID of the item that was added. By default, if the file name is a match, it updates the existing item and does not create a new item.